# Run Ubuntu on an iMac G5

Tags: 12.04, mac, live-cd, powerpc

I have an old iMac G5 (without a webcam) that I would like to get running Ubuntu.  The iMac has no hard drive in it, and I would like to get a live CD running so I can test out Ubuntu before I buy a hard drive to boot from, but I'm having trouble running the live CD.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 PowerPC live desktop build from here (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/, 5th link down) and burned on to a DVD-R at the lowest speed.

When I put it in my iMac and held down the 'C' key to boot from a CD/DVD, the SuperDrive spins up, spins down, and ejects the disk.  The iMac then displays a folder with a question mark superimposed on it (the icon for a missing startup disk).

I've read that this means the CD is not suitable to boot on that computer.  According to the Ubuntu PowerPC FAQ (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ), my iMac **is** compatible.

- Am I downloading the wrong download?
- Do I need a different CD/DVD?
- Is my download of Ubuntu corrupted?
- Why won't can't I get my DVD boot?

Comment: Can you check the ISO you downloaded was a) downloaded without error and b) was burnt to disk without error. The following page should help you do that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto#Check_the_ISO

Comment: Are you copying the iso file to the DVD, or installing it? If you are not installing it properly, you will get this error, as the boot sector will take a look at it and think that it's just a file, not an OS.

Comment: Yes that's a fair point. It's not enough to just copy the ISO onto a DVD as a file, you have to use something that will unpack it. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto and http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: I burned the .iso to a DVD using Disk Utility on my newer Mac the way https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto says to.

Comment: Anyone have any help?

Comment: have you tried a bootable USB ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this : [How do I boot the live CD on a Macbook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71189/how-do-i-boot-the-live-cd-on-a-macbook-pro)

hold alt/opt and select cd,

alternatively, you can install refit on the imac, insert cd and boot from the refit menu

http://refit.sourceforge.net/

It might work, unless the cd is really corrupted